# Convert cumulative value to individual values

Tags: r, cumsum

I have a cumulative value

```
x <- cumsum(1:10)
1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

I want to generate the individual values

```
x - lag(x, default = first(x))
0  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

How can the first value of `x` be 1. It's showing as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the difference. The first value in `x` won't change, so we can begin with `x[1]`.

```
c(x[1], diff(x))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```